# How do I exit memtest86+?

Tags: memtest

I am stuck in memtest86+ 5.01. I can't figure out to get out of it. I tried <kbd>Esc</kbd>. But it again starts doing memtest. The memtest is downloaded from new Ubuntu 18.04 version so it doesn't need any CD or disk. I also tried <kbd>Clt</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> but it doesn't work either. Please, can any one tell me how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 5):

Memtest86 may be configured during operation via runtime configuration commands. Pressing the <kbd>c</kbd> key at any time will display the runtime command menu. When running the UEFI version, the following options are available in the Configuration command menu:

Settings:
   (1) Skip Current Test
   (2) End Test
   (3) Go Back to Main Menu
   (0) Continue

The runtime configuration commands allow the user to adjust the following settings.

(1) Skip Current Test- Aborts the current test and starts the next test in the sequence
   (2) End Test - Stops the test and displays a summary of the results
   (3) Go Back to Main Menu – Stops the test and returns to the main menu
   (0) Continue - Resume the test

Selecting option (3) will return to the Main Menu which has an Exit option for exiting Memtest86. When running the BIOS version, there isn't an option in the Configuration command menu to return to the Main Menu.

Interrupting memtest86+ won't do anything, since it never writes any persistent data. If pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key doesn't exit from the memtest86+ session, you can safely abort memtest86+ at any time simply by switching off the computer.

Comment: This did not help me.
Doing ctrl + alt + delete got me to my settings and I switch boot list option to UEFI but it now boots up with an F1 option to retry reboot, F2 for setup utility or F3 for diagnostics. Nothing to get me back to my desktop.